# Solve issue with circular reference in directive wrapping in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Lets see, I have this javascript widget -- my_widget. The widget expects a model and creates itself. User interacts with the widget and the widget fires an event. The directive listens to the event and updates the 2 way bounded model. When the directive updates the 2 way bounded model the my_widget also updates, which I don't want because it was the cause of the event firing which caused the update in the first place. In code its something like so:

```
app.directive('my_widget',function(){
 scope: {
     model : '='
 },
 link: function(scope,element){
   element.my_widget(); //initialize element to be my_widget
   scope.$watch('model',function(){
      //update my_widget when model is changed. my_widget makes a copy of scope.model
      element.my_widget('setModel',scope.model); 
   });
   element.on('my_widget::changed',function(data){
     //update scope.model, which gets changed to reflect the change in my_widget.
     //but this fires the above model listener, which I don't want because my_widget
     //is already up to date
      _updateModel(scope.model,data);
   });
 }
});
```

I hope my problem is clear enough. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to handle this scenario? When  the event gets fired, scope.model will be changed, which in turns will cause the scope.model listener to fire, which will tell my_widget to use the new model, which I don't want.

Currently my solution is to have a state variable -- ignoreUpdate, which get sets to true inside the event listener function and that state variable is checked in the scope.model watch and if set ignore the update and resets the state variable.

EDIT:

```
Two listeners in drct.js

1)  
    - watchCollection on $scope.models
      - on change, $element.widget('update',$scope.models); #note element.widget does not update $scope.models, it simply just uses its data to display UI
2)
    - $element.on('usermodifiedmodel')
      - on change, update $scope.models
Workflow:
  - 1) user uses the widget and the widget fires usermodifiedmodel event

  - 2) in drct.js $element.on('usermodifiedmodel') catches the event
        - changes $scope.models
  - 3) $scope.models is changed, so in drct.js watchCollection on $scope.models gets triggered
       - in watch collection, $scope.models has changed, so executes $element.widget('update',$scope.models)
         - but the widget is already updated because it started here from user interaction. Hence an extra UI update happens here. Trying to avoid this extra update. Currently using a boolean variable to ignore update if the change came from within the directive.
```

Hope thats clear.

Comment: No actually that is not the issue at hand. I don't think I explained clearly enough. I will edit my original post now

Comment: @ExpertSystem Updated the edit to hopefully be a more clearer question

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if `model` has changed and update your_widget only if necessary:

```
scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
    element.my_widget('setModel', newValue);
});
```